# Is it possible to represent Aluminum 6061 (AlMgSiCuCr) as a skeletal structure?

Tags: structural-formula

Is it possible to represent Aluminum 6061 (AlMgSiCuCr) as a skeletal formula / structure?

Linear Formula: Al-97.9% Mg-1% Si-0.6% Fe-0.4% Cu-0.28%
(possibly helpful)

Here's an example of what I mean...

[image: Example]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The ratio between the different elements is a 100% fixed ratio of small integers in an organic molecule like the one you show.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, probably no.  When you see copper in aluminum (as in the 6xxx series), it is probably there in small amounts for purposes of [precipitation hardening](https://www.totalmateria.com/page.aspx?ID=CheckArticle&site=ktn&NM=235).  In this case, there are tiny discrete precipitates of copper alloys or intermetallic compounds finely dispersed throughout the [aluminum/silicon](https://www.asminternational.org/documents/10192/1849770/06993G_Chapter_1.pdf) matrix.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. There is no repeating crystal unit.

Comment: And perhaps even more to the point, 6061 aluminum it is not even a single phase, which is very common for engineering alloys. The (usually) small amounts of second phases are what gives the alloy the desired mechanical properties.

Comment: Is it one of those icosahedral phases I've heard about?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to check the phase diagram for the system, it may be difficult (or impossible) to get a phase diagram where Al, Si, Cu, Mg and Fe can all be varried independently of each other.

But as a start you should look at the Al / Si, Al / Cu, Al / Mg and Al / Fe phase diagrams.

Under some conditions you might have a solid solution of the dopant atoms in aluminium metal as the "solvent", under these conditions you will have a disordered solid in which some aluminium atoms are randomly replaced with things like copper.

I worry that it is not clear if the % of the elements is given in mass (weight) % or atomic %. So I think it makes the question a bit harder to answer. This book [chapter](http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~mmedraj/tmg-books/Al-Multicomponent%20Phase%20Diagrams/Chapter%202%20-%20Alloys%20of%20the%20Al_Mg_Si_Fe%20System.pdf) may help to make things a bit more clear.